# Django many-to-many query

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

Hello
I have the following Model:

```
class Participation(models.Model):
    workflow_activity = models.ForeignKey('WorkflowActivity')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
    current = models.BooleanField()
```

This is the many-to-many 'through' table.
I want to filter instances of `workflow_activity` that have either one of these conditions:

1. No users assigned, ie, no entries for that workflow_activity in the Participation table
2. No current active users, ie, where all the rows for workflow_activity in the Participation table have `current==False`

Help with building the query would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Hey everyone, thanks for the responses. I guess im probably approaching this thing wrong. My requirement is that im building a sort of ticketing system that has an auto assign function which assigns users to the tickets based on some selection logic. Im running the assign function as a periodic task (using celery), but for that i need to select tickets that are currently unassigned for the current state of the ticket. The current boolean is used to mark if that particular user is assigned to the current state of the ticket.

Any ideas/thoughts on implementing this?

**Edit2**

Heres one i thought of:

```
class WorkflowActivity(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    assigned_to = models.ManytoManyField('Participation') # older table without the current field
    current = models.ManytoManyField('Current')

class Current(models.Model):
    participant = models.ForeignKey('Participation')
```

Cringe-worthy I know, but its what i could come up with, any other options?

Comment: I'm interested in this one... I tried a few ideas but they didn't work very well : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, this should work:

```
from django.db.models import Count

WorkflowActivity.objects.annotate(users=Count('participation__user')).filter(users=0)
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a good way to do #2 using only built-ins in Django's ORM.  You could try extending the `Count` type, as suggested in [Ticket 11305](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11305).

**Edit:**

If you are interested in finding all `WorkflowActivities` that have at least one active `User`, you can do:

```
WorkflowActivity.objects.filter(participation__current=True)
```

Comment: What about if we think about it the other way around? Instead of *all* rows have current==False, just find the ones where *at least* one is not false.

Comment: Sure, that would be doable.  It's just a minor change from my annotation for #1.

Comment: for #1, you can just use a standard query: WorkflowActivity.objects.filter(participation__isnull=True) #2 is...  a problem.

Comment: @Yuji: isnull refers specifically to the value of a field, which means that it won't do what you think in this case.

Comment: @Jeff Bradberry, why not? It will return all `WorkflowActivity` objects that have 0 relations pointing to them. Is this wrong? (I use the syntax often so I'd like to know the pitfalls!)

Comment: Huh.  Apparently it does: 'SELECT "foo_workflowactivity"."id", "foo_workflowactivity"."text" FROM "foo_workflowactivity" LEFT OUTER JOIN "foo_participation" ON ("foo_workflowactivity"."id" = "foo_participation"."workflow_activity_id") WHERE "foo_participation"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 21'.  (This can be found by doing 'from django.db import connection' and then looking at connection.queries.)

Comment: Hey thanks for the responses, i had figured out #1, was stuck with #2 :D, anyways, have updated my question with what im trying to implement, any ideas if there is another way of accomplishing this?